# CSS overide doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to override the style to all the img tag in `<div class="profile-activity">`

Here is what I've tried

```
<style type="text/css">
    .profile-activity img {
        width: 200px !important;
        border: red 2px solid;
    }
</style>



<img class="" id="Company Logo" src="/files/logo_path/{{$user->id}}" alt="User's Photo"  width="200" >
```

### UPDATED

I want to force my `internal` css to overide my `external` css. 
My `!important` doesn't work.
The width doesn't take effect, but the border does.

Result

[image]

Comment: can you please provide a link?

Comment: `.profile-activity img`...

Comment: Can you provide the `<img>` code as well?

Comment: @Hynes : I just added, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @evoque2015 I'm a bit confused. You have a width of 200px on the `<img>`, but you're also declaring 200px within your CSS. Is 200px the native image width?

Comment: I tried to set it in both places, but none of them work. Surprisingly, the border work. ???

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/c8ag8upx/1/, note I removed the width attribute from the image so you can remove the width declaration in the CSS to test.

Answer (score 6):

`>` indicates the child only in css. `img` is not a child of `profile-activity`, hence the issue

Change the CSS from

```
.profile-activity > img {
    width: 200px !important;
    border: red 2px solid;
}
```

To Either:

```
.profile-activity img {
    width: 200px !important;
    border: red 2px solid;
}
```

OR

```
.profile-activity > div > img {
    width: 200px !important;
    border: red 2px solid;
}
```

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first.

Comment: I tried that. Only some of it work. The width, didn't work. See [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/width.JPG). Do you know why ?

Comment: I would recommend you to create a fiddle with your current code. Just looking at the JPG is not sufficient.

Comment: I just realize that. This is not a normal. My main external css is huge. My goal, I want to use my internal css to overide my external css. But for some reasons my !important doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, This might be a great opportunity to learn how to debug CSS issues (if you havent done that already ) - Chrome and Firefox have very powerful developer tools. There, you can see the CSS being applied, and identify what needs to change. Also, If you are inserting the stylesheets inline, make sure that the css rules are _below_ the reference to the CSS file

Comment: I kind of know about that. But isn't `!important` suppose to force set it ? ... so far thank-you for your helps.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes - However, it would be very hard to speculate without actually looking at the css, etc.. On another note, it looks like you are applying border radius, etc to the wrapper around the image - I would look into the css related to that to see what is going on..

Comment: `!important` should be avoided, it is a bit of a last resort sort of thing.

Comment: Did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped your `<img>` inside a div, you will need to either add a class to the nested div and call it on that or make sure you call the parent of the parent div

```
.profile-activity > div > img {
    width: 200px !important;
   border: red 2px solid;
}
```